# $ImT$ is closed. Does this imply that $T^{-1}$ is a bounded operator?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let 
$$ T:C[0,1]\rightarrow C[0,1]
$$
bounded and linear map. Also, $T$ is not surjective.

Suppose $ImT$ is closed. Does this imply that $T^{-1}$ is a bounded operator? I think it does, but I do not see how to prove it.

Comment: I assume you want $T^{-1}$ to be defined on the range of $T$?

Comment: this is only true if the range of $T$ is closed.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Yes, that's it.

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek the range of $T$ is $ImT$...

Comment: Have you seen the [Closed Graph Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_graph_theorem)?  It says that if the set $\{(x,y)\in C[0,1]\times C[0,1]\mid Tx = y\}$ is closed in the product topology, then $T$ is continuous.

Comment: You need that $T$ is injective to have an inverse $T^{-1}:$ Im$(T)\to C[0,1]$.